# A neat way to divide in two and reorder a list?

Tags: c#

I have an ordered list like this:

```
var list = new List<String>(){"aaa","aab","aac","baa","bab","bac"};
```

I want to cut the list in half and reverse the order of the halves, while retaining the order of the two sub lists. The only way I can think of doing that is like this:

```
var list = new List<String>() { "aaa", "aab", "aac", "baa", "bab", "bac" };
int index = list.IndexOf("aac");
var tempList = new List<String>(list.GetRange(index, list.Count - index));
tempList.AddRange(list.GetRange(0, index));
list = tempList;
```

This takes 5 lines and a temporary variable, and doesn't look very nice.

Is there a neater way to do this? I thought that it should be possible with Linq, but most of those methods don't seem to care about the order of the underlying list.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `Take` and `Skip`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably shorter, but it might be slower:

```
 var list = new List<String> { "aaa", "aab", "aac", "baa", "bab", "bac" };
 var index = list.IndexOf("aac");
 var r = list.Skip(index).Concat(list.Take(index)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

As Daniel says, using LINQ ends up with a simple solution:

```
int splitIndex = 5; // Or whatever
var result = list.Skip(splitIndex)
                 .Concat(list.Take(splitIndex)).ToList();
```

It won't be as efficient as it might be, but it's neater :)

It's worth remembering that assuming the sequence is stable (e.g. `List<T>`), `sequence.Take(x)` and `sequence.Skip(x)` always divides it into two disjoint sequences which cover the entire sequence. The same is true for `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile`.